# When does system_requirements function runs?

Tags: cron

When does Drupal call [`system_requirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.install/function/system_requirements/9), which hardens permissions for files and for directories containing them?
Does Drupal call it in each cron run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`system_requirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21system.install/function/system_requirements/9) is a [`hook_requirements()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_requirements/9) implementation by the System module, which is one of the required Drupal core modules. (It means it's installed on every Drupal site.)

`hook_requirements()` implementations are invoked when:

- Modules are installed from the UI
- The site status report is shown
- A database update page is shown

For what I can see, Drupal core doesn't invoke `hook_requirements()` implementations during cron tasks, but a contributed or a custom module could invoke them when cron tasks are executed. They are invoked when /update.php is accessed, though.